# JQuery Disable Spacebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've found following script to disable the spacebar:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("input").on("keydown", function (e) {
return e.which !== 32;
});
});//]]>  
</script>
```

Except that disables all input's on any page it's implemented. I need it to disable just one text input. How can I do that?

Comment: `jQuery` uses a `css selector` like syntax to select the elements, which you need to pass to the `$(...)` function, refer to the manual on jquery.com

Comment: Also depending on what the exact intended result is you may need an `e.preventdefault` call in the event callback.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of binding to all inputs, use a selector binding only to your specific input. This input probably has an id, say `myInput`.

Then, use this :

```
$("#myInput").on("keydown", function (e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("input")` matches all inputs. To target a specific element, use:

`$('#id')` where `id` is the id of your input element.